# How to get workflow taskId of the current task of current user in liferay?

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I am working in liferay and using Kaleo Workflow. I wish to get workflow taskId of the current task of current user in liferay?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on this question

Comment: you want to get the current taskId in your liferay code? where? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This code from the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672441/perform-workflow-transition-programmatically-in-liferay) can help you to get taskID.

```
JournalArticle journalArticle = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(id);
            getPermissionChecker().init(u.getUser(), true);
        WorkflowInstanceLink wil= WorkflowInstanceLinkLocalServiceUtil.getWorkflowInstanceLink(companyId, journalArticle.getGroupId(), JournalArticle.class.getName(), journalArticle.getId());
        WorkflowInstance workflowInstance = WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.getWorkflowInstance(companyId, wil.getWorkflowInstanceId());
        Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext = workflowInstance.getWorkflowContext();

        List<Integer> logTypes_assign = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        logTypes_assign.add(WorkflowLog.TASK_ASSIGN);
        List<WorkflowLog> workflowLogs_assign = WorkflowLogManagerUtil.getWorkflowLogsByWorkflowInstance(companyId, wil.getWorkflowInstanceId(), logTypes_assign, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, WorkflowComparatorFactoryUtil.getLogCreateDateComparator(true));
        //WorkflowPermissionUtil.hasPermission(permissionChecker, groupId, className, classPK, actionId);

        if(workflowLogs_assign.size() > 0){             
            long taskId = workflowLogs_assign.get(workflowLogs_assign.size()-1).getWorkflowTaskId();
            WorkflowTask task = WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.getWorkflowTask(companyId, taskId);
            _log.info("task : "+task.getName());
            WorkflowTask nextTask = WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.assignWorkflowTaskToUser(companyId, userId, task.getWorkflowTaskId(), userId, "auto assign", task.getDueDate(), workflowContext);               
            WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.completeWorkflowTask(companyId, userId, nextTask.getWorkflowTaskId(), "next task transition name", "next task name", workflowContext);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: There was no explanation to this, so I am also in need of some explanation if anyone can provide.