# Perform workflow transition programmatically in liferay?

Tags: content-management-system, workflow, portlet, liferay-6

I have two transition named "approved" and "reject" at the lastest step of my workflow, but i want to controll the workflow action from my portlet.

Anybody know How to Perform workflow transition programmatically in liferay ?

Answer (score 3):

my current code

```
  JournalArticle journalArticle = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(id);
            getPermissionChecker().init(u.getUser(), true);

            WorkflowInstanceLink wil= WorkflowInstanceLinkLocalServiceUtil.getWorkflowInstanceLink(companyId, journalArticle.getGroupId(), JournalArticle.class.getName(), journalArticle.getId());
            WorkflowInstance workflowInstance = WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.getWorkflowInstance(companyId, wil.getWorkflowInstanceId());
            Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext = workflowInstance.getWorkflowContext();

            List<Integer> logTypes_assign = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            logTypes_assign.add(WorkflowLog.TASK_ASSIGN);
            List<WorkflowLog> workflowLogs_assign = WorkflowLogManagerUtil.getWorkflowLogsByWorkflowInstance(companyId, wil.getWorkflowInstanceId(), logTypes_assign, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, WorkflowComparatorFactoryUtil.getLogCreateDateComparator(true));
            //WorkflowPermissionUtil.hasPermission(permissionChecker, groupId, className, classPK, actionId);

            if(workflowLogs_assign.size() > 0){             
                long taskId = workflowLogs_assign.get(workflowLogs_assign.size()-1).getWorkflowTaskId();
                WorkflowTask task = WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.getWorkflowTask(companyId, taskId);
                _log.info("task : "+task.getName());
                WorkflowTask nextTask = WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.assignWorkflowTaskToUser(companyId, userId, task.getWorkflowTaskId(), userId, "auto assign", task.getDueDate(), workflowContext);               
                WorkflowTaskManagerUtil.completeWorkflowTask(companyId, userId, nextTask.getWorkflowTaskId(), "next task transition name", "next task name", workflowContext);
            }
```

Comment: user1487380 how do you use workflow in this example? are you attaching a kaleo workflow? I would love to do workflow transitions with code. but i would like to know if your question also apllied to kaleo? see my question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180974/kaleo-designer-and-liferay-6-1 Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please tell us how you get to this code, as I could not find any explanation or documentation to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
workflowInstance1 = WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.signalWorkflowInstance(service.getCompanyId(), user.getUserId(),
            workflowInstanceId, transitionNAME, workflowInstance.getWorkflowContext());
```

Comment: a little bit of explanation would be very helpful :)