# Kaleo designer and Liferay 6.1

Tags: workflow, liferay-6

I'm looking for information about kaleo and if i should implement it in my system. A.T.M. i have a custom workflow implemented but some of my co-workers say that a kaleo workflow is easier to maintain. I would like to have some opinions about my issue. Thanks in advance.

I think that there might be a problem with the way that my system is build. I have multiple portlets that all have web content(Journal Articles) as there resource. Every portlet has a different workflow with custom update functions to maintain relations that are made.

Is it possible to implement the kaleo workflow on this concept? because on the internet i only find information about custom entities and not on Journal Articles.

some opinions, solutions and any other information is appreciated!

Comment: I think if you want to choose kaleo, you will need to know some pros and cons. The biggest problem i found when choose kaleo is: hard to customize ROLE, and it have flexible interfaces, easy to meet some javascript error. HOWEVER pros: hightly customizable. p/s: we can have workflow for each structure by using default values category and some of code.

Comment: My customer want to have more simple interfaces, so i have spent alot of working time to simpler it :)) they just want to upload their content and approve in 2 step

Comment: Did you change the updateStatus method from the Journal article? and how? or wasn't that needed for your case?

Comment: nope, but i change the workflow definition, in my custom-workflow-def.xml i use velocity script to connect to database, and use workflowlog to check what is next transition.